# Fill column based on three other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A: In WorkSheet1 I have one column A with 2000 page urls.

B: In WorkSheet2 I have one column B with 200 page urls of the 2000 page urls from column A in WorkSheet1.

C: In WorkSheet2 I also have one column C with page visits for all the 200 urls in column B.

In WorkSheet1 I want to insert the page visits from WorkSheet2 column C where the page url in column A matches with the page url from column B in WorkSheet2.

The result should be a new column in WorkSheet1 listed with page visits for 200 of the 2000 urls for column A.

What excel-formula do I need to accomplish this?

Comment: Try using Vlookup or Index with match.

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply it? I'm new to excel

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I would suggest Index/Match. It's two formulas, one is Index(array, row_ref, col_ref) and the second is Match(lookup_value, lookup_array, match_type)

When you use them together, you get something that looks like this:
=index('sheet2'!B:B, match(a1,'sheet2'!A:A,0))

The argument in INDEX is the column you want to return, then, the first argument in match is the lookup value of the first url, then the second argument is the column that those URL's are in in reference to your indexed array. The third argument in match is "0" which indicates you want an exact match and not a match greater or less than your lookup value.

The other option is to use a Pivot table to sort views by URL. This can be a little trickier because you have to use a slicer and connect two pivots with the slicer.